# Amcharts - Stacked Column/Pie chart - Reduce opacity of other stacks/pies

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I've managed to implement the feature where in a stacked column chart, when I hover over one of the many stacks that are joined together, the opacity changes.

What I'm after is to reduce the opacity of all the other stacks except the one I'm hovering on.

```
 /*
 *      Graph opacity
 */

 function setOpacity(graph, opacity) {
        var className = "amcharts-graph-" + graph.id;
        var items = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        if (undefined === items)
            return;
        for (var x in items) {
            if ("object" !== typeof items[x])
                continue;
            var path = items[x].getElementsByTagName("path")[ 0 ];
            if (undefined !== path)
                path.style.fillOpacity = opacity;
        }
    }

/*
 *      Handle hover event
 */
function addOnHoverListner(chartObj) {
    chartObj.timeout;
    chartObj.addListener("rollOverGraph", function (event) {
        setOpacity(event.graph, 0.5);
    });
    chartObj.addListener("rollOutGraph", function (event) {
        setOpacity(event.graph, 1);
    });

    chartObj.addListener("init", function () {
        chartObj.categoryAxis.addListener("clickItem", function (event) {
            //alert("clicked axis label");
        });
    });
}
```

Is this possible? Please can I request guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code can easily be modified to do that. Instead of just increasing the opacity of the graph being rolled over. Simply cycle through **all** of the graphs and reduce the opacity of them except the one currently being hovered on:

```
chart.addListener( "rollOverGraph", function( event ) {
  var chart = event.chart;
  for(var i = 0; i < chart.graphs.length; i++) {
    setOpacity( chart.graphs[i] , event.graph === chart.graphs[i] ? 1 : 0.5 );
  }

} );
chart.addListener( "rollOutGraph", function( event ) {
  var chart = event.chart;
  for(var i = 0; i < chart.graphs.length; i++) {
    setOpacity( chart.graphs[i] , 1 );
  }
} );
```

Here's a [working example](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/22c99cc9aa69fcfec0b20a9e0bd5b408).

Comment: Thank you Martyn. Kind as ever. Appreciate your help.